# System of equations on $\mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, real-numbers, 3d

$\textbf{Question : }$ Find all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the following system of equations.
$$3x-4y+\frac{1}{xy}=12$$ $$4z-12x+\frac{1}{zx}=3$$ $$12y-3z+\frac{1}{yz}=4$$

$\textbf{My Attempt :}$
Let $t = \frac{1}{xyz}$ then each of our equation transforms to

$$3x-4y+tz=12$$ $$-12x+ty+4z=3$$ $$tx+12y-3z=4$$

I thought I would zero out the coefficient matrix which led to nothing :

$$\Delta = -t^3-169t=0 \implies t = 0 ,\pm13i$$ none of which is in $t$'s domain as $t \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$

Next I thought to write it in a form where all the constant terms are zero so I could surely zero out the coefficient matrix and find out the value of $t$. So here are those equations $$51x-4y(t+1)+z(t-16)=0$$ $$3(t+16)x+4(9-t)y-25z=0$$ $$3(1-t)x-40y+z(t+9)=0$$

as it turns out the coefficient matrix is zero for all $t \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$. So what to do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve the set of equations you have $$3x-4y+tz=12$$ $$-12x+ty+4z=3$$ $$tx+12y-3z=4$$for $x$, $y$ and $z$ in terms of $t$. It looks as if it will be horrible, but in fact you can eliminate $y$, for example, to get (multiply first equation by t and second by 4, then add) $$(3t-48)x+(t^2+16)z=12t+12$$ and (then multiply first equation by 3 and add to last) $$(t+9)x+(3t-3)z=40.$$ Now multiply the first of these equations by $(3t-3)$ and the second by $(t^2+16)$ and subtract, to get $$(9(t-1)(t-16)-(t+9)(t^2+16))x=36(t^2-1)-40(t^2+16)$$ or $$(-t^3-169t)x=-4(t^2+169),$$ so
$x= \dfrac{4}{t}$ and back substitution gives $y= \dfrac{3}{t}$ and $z= \dfrac{12}{t}$.

Then $t= \dfrac{1}{xyz} = \dfrac{t^3}{144}$, so $t=\pm 12$, which completes the solution.

Comment: could you explain how step by step how you got x = 4/t ? I dont understand what you mean "by elimination", by elimination of what? you are skipping out too many steps for me!

Comment: @Commenter I've expanded my solution. Is that sufficient for you?

Comment: @mcd I have trawled through it, and I now understand the steps, and you rely on t being real. if t were complex you would have the problem of t^2 + 169 =0 to deal with.

Comment: one further question is that with all the solutions so far, they put t = 1/xyz, but this seems like a rabbit pulled out of a hat, where or how did you logically arrive at setting t = 1/xyz? seems like an outright nonsequitur!

Comment: @mcd although the question is about real solutions, how would you deal with t = +- 13i? are there complex solutions where that is the case, if not, how would you show that?

Comment: @mcd I have a completely different answer. Have you seen it ?

Answer (score 4):

If you write your system of equations in a reverse order :

$$\begin{cases}tx+12y-3z&=&4\\-12x+ty+4z&=&3\\3x-4y+tz&=&12\end{cases} \iff $$

$$\begin{cases}12y-3z&=&4-tx\\-12x+4z&=&3-ty\\3x-4y&=&12-tz\end{cases},$$

you recognize in the LHS a cross-product :

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}4\\3\\12\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\3\\12\end{pmatrix}-t\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

Otherwise said, with evident notations :

$$X \times V = V - tX \tag{1}$$

(1) looks not to have any solution because $X \times V$ is orthogonal to both $X$ and $V$, therefore cannot lie (as indicated by the RHS) in the plane generated by $V$ and $X$.

**But**, in fact there is solution iff both sides of (1) are zero, i.e., $V=tX \ \iff X=\tfrac1t V$ :

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{t}\begin{pmatrix}4\\3\\12\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4/t\\3/t\\12/t\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

It's time to remember that $t=\frac{1}{xyz}$ :

$$t=\frac{1}{(4/t).(3/t).(12/t)}$$

finaly giving $t=\pm 12$.

Having $t$, the solutions are directly obtained from (2).

Comment: Having a relationship like (1) is not due to chance : The repeating presence of the same coefficients $3, 4, 12$ make me think that people who have conceived this exercise had cross product in mind...

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: this is a very elegant solution! Its the only solution so far which shows also there are no complex solutions, the other solutions have the problem of t=+-13i for the complex case. ie it answers a bigger question! I am still mystified how the questioner thought of setting t = 1/xyz, as that is key to all the solutions so far. I find it strange to solve an equation in terms of a dependent variable! I noticed the skew symmetry of the coefficients, but couldnt see how to leverage that as I wasnt thinking in terms of cross product but in terms of diagonalising matrices.

Comment: @Commenter Thanks for your answer. In fact, it is not so strange to set $t=\frac{1}{xyz}$ ; I understand your concern about $t$ being a dependent variable, but it could/should be seen differently : the surface $S_t$ with this equation $\frac{1}{xyz}=t$ (with hyperbolic level sets) browses, when $t$ varies, all the space (apart the coordinate planes but no solution exist in these planes) and we are looking for the intersections of our locus with this moving surface...

Comment: @ Jean Marie, I specialised in pure maths, so I tend to think in terms of pathological examples and symbols, I never got the hang of vector calculus eg div, grad, curl, as I only did that in the first year and couldnt keep up. What text book would you recommend to cover the basics of div, grad and curl, as there is a jungle of textbooks, and each textbook is itself a jungle! I tried solving the first equation as a quadratic in x, and got a very complicated expression for x in terms of y and gave up!

Comment: Here is a very good little book on this subject: https://archive.org/details/H.M.ScheyDivGradCurlAndAllThat

Comment: @ Jean Marie, many thanks for the link, I have now purchased the book from ebay! BTW with the equations, if we re-express them as polynomials eg 1st one becomes 3x^2y-4xy^2+1 = 12xy, its then a question of algebraic geometry, which wont help solve the equations, but as it is 3 cubics, provided they are "independent", I think it should mean 3 x 3 x 3=27 solutions, possibly /at infinity/multiple/complex. Thus the solutions you found are probably multiple. eg in the plane 2 quadratics intersect at 2 x 2 points. For the plane its Bezout's theorem: generalisation of polynomial f has degree(f) zeros

Comment: Happy it has helped. You are right about cubic equations. My "initial vision" of the system was geometric (of a different type) : as each  equation depends on 2 parameters, they define (generalized) cylinders in the direction of Ox, Oy, Oz. The intersection of the two first gives a curve, this curve with the third one give some (real) points.

Comment: @ Jean Marie, the Algebraic Geometry MO is then to homogenise the equations,by bringing in a 4th variable say u,eg to then get 3xxy - 4xyy + uuu = 12xyu,here "affine coordinates" (x,y,z) are mapped to "projective coordinates" (x,y,z,1),where in projective space (x,y,z,u) = v*(x,y,z,u) for v any non zero constant.u=0 is then the plane at infinity for those affine coordinates.You can study that by looking at a different affine space eg x=1, and then set u=0, where I suspect there will be some further projective solutions,ought to be 27 points in total!projective space "completes" affine space

Comment: @ Jean Marie, further to earlier, in projective space over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0, such as complex numbers and algebraic numbers, you get nice theorems, eg that the number of solutions is the product of the degrees of the functions, subject to them being "independent". whereas in affine space, some solutions are lost at infinity eg 2 coplanar lines always meet at one point, but for parallel lines this point is at infinity! But Algebraic geometry is very difficult subject.

Comment: as an example, 2 concentric circles in the real plane dont intersect, eg xx+yy=1 and xx+yy=4, but if we homogenise these to get xx+yy=zz and xx+yy=4zz, we find z=0, and y=+-i, ie (1,i,0) and (1,-i,0) in the complex line at infinity. I think these must be double points, as there should be 2x2 solutions. But I havent done this stuff for years, so I would have to study the theory as to how to show they are double points. I think you have to look at the intersection of ideals in a local ring, but there may be a clever more direct way. AG is very interesting, but also quite tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why you equate $\Delta$ to zero. Instead, at that juncture, you could have easily apply Cramer's rule as shown below.

$$x=\dfrac{
\begin{bmatrix}
12 & -4& t \\
3 & t & 4 \\
4 & 12 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}}{\Delta} =\dfrac{-36t-576-100+36t-4t^2}{-t\left(t^2+169\right)}=\dfrac{-676-4t^2}{-t\left(t^2+169\right)}=\dfrac{t}{4}.
$$

Similarly, the other two unknowns $y$ and $z$ can be expressed in terms of $t$ by simplifying the two equation given below.

$$y=\dfrac{
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 12& t \\
-12 & 3 & 4 \\
t & 4 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}}{\Delta} \qquad\text{and}\qquad 
z=\dfrac{
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -4 & 12 \\
-12 & t & 3 \\
t & 12 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}}{\Delta}
$$